# Chrome extensions: is native messaging deprecated?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When navigating to ["native massaging" documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/), first thing you see is a warning:

> Important: Chrome will be removing support for Chrome Apps on all
> platforms. Chrome browser and the Chrome Web Store will continue to
> support extensions. Read the announcement and learn more about
> migrating your app.

Since all this documentation located under Chrome Apps docs, is it means that "native messaging" feature going away as well? If it is, what is the alternative for communicating with chrome extension from the outside?

Comment: No, it's the documentation server is still broken for several months and it links to the wrong page. Chromium team thinks it's an acceptable state of affairs.